# How to configure Openlayers for a flat 1:1 pixel coordinate system?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to build a map for the game Guild Wars 2, but having trouble getting openlayers to handle the coordinate system correctly and render the map completely.

Here's a fiddle of what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/ndqb8rqx/

The Guild Wars world is square and 49152 pixels on both axes. The origin (`[0, 0]`) of the coordinates should be the north-west. The south-east should be `[49152, 49152]`. The developer of the game makes the tiles for the map available as a service: https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:Tile_service

I created a `Projection` based on Zoomify to try to handle this:

```
var gw2Projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'ZOOMIFY',
  units: 'pixels',
  extent: [0, -49152, 49152, 0]
})
```

And I also added the game tiles as a Tilelayer from an XYZ source, like this:

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'https://tiles.guildwars2.com/1/1/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg',
    projection: gw2Projection
  }),
}),
```

The first problem is that openlayers doesn't render the complete map. The map actually extends further south and east than the fiddle shows. The bottom right edge which is actually shown in the fiddle is really `[32768, 32768]`, but the map extends out to `[49152, 49152]`. It seems that openlayers simply shrinks the coordinate system to the area of a single tile when zoomed completely out. Instead I would like the coordinates to match 1:1 with the pixels.

The other problem is that currently the y-coordinate increase in the northern direction. I would like to invert the y-axis, such that the y-coordinates increase in the southern direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ahocevar nudged me in the right direction. The suggestion of creating a custom tilegrid was necessary but instead of setting the zoom level, it was necessary to set the actual resolutions.

So by adding a tilegrid like this:

```
var tilegrid = new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
  extent: extent,
  resolutions: [128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
});
```

Using it in the layer source like this:

```
source: new ol.source.XYZ({
  tileGrid: tilegrid,
  url: 'https://tiles.guildwars2.com/1/1/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg',
  projection: gw2Projection
}),
```

And finally adding it to the view as well:

```
view: new ol.View({
  center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
  zoom: 1,
  projection: gw2Projection,
  extent:extent,
  resolutions: tilegrid.getResolutions()
})
```

The entire map is now shown, and the coordinates are correct. The Y-axis is still negative though.

Here's a fiddle with the result, I also included the TileDebug layer for good measure: https://jsfiddle.net/kay99yor/1/

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out for almost a week now. thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

The key to making this work is a custom tile grid definition, i.e. with the correct extent and maxZoom:

```
var tilegrid = new ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
  extent: gw2Projection.getExtent(),
  maxZoom: 7
});
```

Then configure the XYZ source with that tilegrid:

```
source: new ol.source.XYZ({
  url: 'https://tiles.guildwars2.com/1/1/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg',
  projection: gw2Projection,
  tileGrid: tilegrid
})
```

Also configure the view with the resolutions of that tilegrid:

```
view: new ol.View({
  center: ol.extent.getCenter(gw2Projection.getExtent()),
  extent: gw2Projection.getExtent(),
  zoom: 1,
  resolutions: tilegrid.getResolutions()
}
```

I have created an updated fiddle that makes your map work: https://jsfiddle.net/kay99yor/.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately I don't really see a difference? 
The coordinates are the same, the y axis direction is still the same, and the missing part of the map is still not showing. The only difference I can see is that you centered the view on the map.